# jQuery accessing listview->ul->li->span->img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my shortcode of `li`.

```
<li>
    <a href='#'><img src='img.png'/>
        <h2 style='margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px'>test</h2>
        <p><strong>{</strong><label>test</label><strong>}</strong></p>
        <p><strong>test</strong></p>
        <p><strong style='font-size: 17px; color: #fff'>10</strong>
        <br/><span id='onoff'><img src='on.png'/></span>
        <span id='delete'><img src='abc.png'/></span></p>
    </a>
</li>
```

As you can see, the `li` contains to the whole html an `<a href>`, which will trigger a file when clicked. That said, I would like to detect the click of the images inside the `span`, both of them separately, `<span id='onoff'>` and `<span id='delete'>`

This is what I've tried so far without any result.

```
$('#page-main-listview ul li span').on("click", function(){
    if(($this).attr("id") == 'onoff'){
        // I dont know what to put here
        // I need to find img now and trigger 'onClick()'
    }
});
```

**Edit:** I think i've solved the issue, this way:

```
$('#page-main-listview').delegate('img', 'click', function(){
    $atrr = $(this).attr("name");
    alert($atrr);
    if($atrr == 'on'){

    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find('img').click()`?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The code above doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also if the pattern is repeated then you should make sure that the ids of elements remain unique in a page... if you have a repeated pattern then use class names to group similar elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny, tried `$(this).find('img').on("click", function(){
     alert("OK");
    });`, after the condition, but nothing shows. About the unique elements, the span element is not unique, but the img inside of it is.

Comment: @user3065191 can you share the complete code you tried

Comment: Of course. See in paste bin for a better perspective. http://pastebin.com/jknVFaut

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, wait for the waiting time to expire, and then select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using span IDs instead of classes within a list which leads me to believe you will have problems when adding more list elements.

To make things easier, `<span data-tag="onoff" class="clickMe">` for the first image link and `<span data-tag="delete" class="clickMe">` for the second. Then you can easily loop through with something like:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('tag'));
});
```